# How to create industry-year average of all variables from firm- year data using Stata?

Tags: panel, stata

I am having a panel dataset with the following format

```
Firm    Year    Industry    Sales   Profit  Export intensity    R&D
1   2000    1   x   x   x   x
2   2000    1   x   x   x   x
3   2000    2   x   x   x   x
4   2000    2   x   x   x   x
1   2001    1   x   x   x   x
2   2001    1   x   x   x   x
3   2001    2   x   x   x   x
4   2001    2   x   x   x   x
1   2002    1   x   x   x   x
2   2002    1   x   x   x   x
3   2002    2   x   x   x   x
4   2002    2   x   x   x   x
1   2003    1   x   x   x   x
2   2003    1   x   x   x   x
3   2003    2   x   x   x   x
4   2003    2   x   x   x   x
```

I want to create industry average per year of all variables. The real data set has 2000 firms * 10 years observations and 25 industries.

Comment: this is a broad and vague question. which tool you are dealing with to create this panel? what's the data source?

Comment: I tried to copy the data from excel to the question but not successfully. It looks a bit messy. But basically, I have firm_year data on sales, profit, export intensity etc. I want to create industry average (average of sales of all firms within an industry) for each year.

Comment: what are your tools (sql server, excel, access, ...)? where does the data comes from (sql database, excel file, mdb database, json file...)? what language you will use to create the panel?

Comment: Oh sorry. I am using STATA 13

Comment: You should at least attempt some code. SO isn't, in my view, a forum for writing code on request, but a forum for programmers to discuss problems with code they are writing.

Comment: Stata has excellent documentation starting with the **User's guide** (http://www.stata.com/bookstore/users-guide/); try taking advantage of it.

Comment: Thanks guys. I had my own solution before I post this, but I was not happy with the solution so :-)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to maintain your data structure, the easiest way is probably to combine `egen`'s `by()` option with a loop:

```
foreach v of varlist Sales Profit Export RD {
    egen IndAvg`v' = mean(`v') , by(Industry Year)
}
```

E.g.,

```
clear all
input Firm    Year    Industry    Sales   Profit  Export    RD 
1   2000          1     831      135      196    30  
2   2000          1      44      847      885   780  
3   2000          2     818      112      859   306  
4   2000          2     777      700      903   858  
1   2001          1     491      563      325   324  
2   2001          1     411      468      927   720  
3   2001          2     731      872      170   556  
4   2001          2     587      273      833   656  
1   2002          1     155      558      497   427  
2   2002          1     210      853      792   575  
3   2002          2     279      282      969   549  
4   2002          2     683      176      902   538  
1   2003          1     805      475      479   599  
2   2003          1     226      178       37   225  
3   2003          2     129      693      746   652  
4   2003          2     347      509      406   102  
end

foreach v of varlist Sales Profit Export RD {
    egen IndAvg`v' = mean(`v') , by(Industry Year)
}

sort Industry Year Firm
li , sepby(Industry)
```

However, you may also want to look into `collapse`:

```
collapse (mean) Sales Profit Export RD , by(Industry Year)
```

Comment: Thanks Bredan. The first option seems to work. But result is duplicated. E.g, industry average appears multiple times. For the data of 2000 firms with 10 years each, the average is gonna repeat 2000 times for each year. I don't think the stata can display the result. Is there anyway you can fix this?

Comment: The structure of the data depends on the end goal of the analysis. In some cases, one would want to include duplicated averages. If you want to maintain your data at an `Industry-Firm-Year` level, then there will be duplicated averages by `Industry-Year`. Otherwise, look into the `collapse` option as noted at the end of the answer, which will reduce your dataset to a single observation per `Industry-Year` (removing `Firm` entirely).

Comment: Thanks Bredan. I will try with the collapse then, since the data is too large to display in result window.

Comment: Displaying in the results window is a convenience (and was included so you could copy and paste the code above into a new Stata session to view the process), and should not determine your data processing choice. Replace `li , sepby(Industry)` with `br` if you prefer.

Comment: Yes, I understand. Thank you so much Bredan